# In Jupyter Notebooks on Google Colab, what's the difference between using % and ! to run a shell command?

Tags: ipython, jupyter, google-colaboratory

Question is in the title.

I know that `%` usually denotes a "magic variable" in IPython. That's not a concept I'm terribly familiar with yet, but I have read about it.

However, today I saw a tutorial where someone was using it to run a shell command. Normally I have seen and used `!`.

Is there a difference? Both seem to be doing the same thing when I try them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The difference is this:

- When you run a command with `!`, it directly executes a bash command in a subshell.
- When you run a command with `%`, it executes one of the [magic commands](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html) defined in IPython.

Some of the magic commands defined by IPython deliberately mirror bash commands, but they differ in the implementation details.

For example, running the `!cd` bash command does not persistently change your directory, because it runs in a temporary subshell. However, running the [`%cd`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-cd) magic command will persistently change your directory:

```
!pwd
# /content

!cd sample_data/
!pwd
# /content

%cd sample_data/
!pwd
# /content/sample_data
```

Read more in [IPython: Built-in Magic Commands](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html).

Comment: Perfect. I just noticed that `! cd` doesn't actually change my directory just before you answered. Now I know why!