# How to install Talib (on windows machine) in colab (2022-12)?

Tags: python, ta-lib

Yesterday I tried to run a python code which contains a talib package. The package failed to run in colab, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'talib'`

I used this code, which normally worked, but after yesterday it didn't.

```
url = 'https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/libta-lib/0.4.0/download/linux-64/libta-lib-0.4.0-h516909a_0.tar.bz2'
!curl -L $url | tar xj -C /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ lib --strip-components=1
url = 'https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ta-lib/0.4.19/download/linux-64/ta-lib-0.4.19-py37ha21ca33_2.tar.bz2'
!curl -L $url | tar xj -C /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ lib/python3.7/site-packages/talib --strip-components=3
```

The idea is to install the following items:

```
import talib as ta
from talib import RSI, BBANDS, MACD
```

I tried this as well, without succes:

```
!pip install TA-Lib as ta
from TA-Lib import RSI, BBANDS, MACD
```

Does someone know how to install this package in colab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) is a notebook, you can use the `!` operator with  [`pip`](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) to install the [`TA-Lib`](https://pypi.org/project/TA-Lib/) package.

Try this :

```
!pip install TA-Lib
```

As suggested by @DarknessPlusPlus, you can also use the magic command `%` :

```
%pip install TA-Lib
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60799846/16120011) by @jakevdp explains the difference between the two commands.

##### # Edit :

If you still can't import the modules, run this in a Google Colab cell :

```
!curl -L http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz -O && tar xzvf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
!cd ta-lib && ./configure --prefix=/usr && make && make install && cd - && pip install ta-lib
```

##### # Result :

[image]

But before that, make sure to uninstall any talib package with :

```
%pip uninstall TA-lib talib-binary
```

Comment: this or instead of `!` use `%`

Comment: Right, I updated my answer ;)

Comment: I can't import RSI, BBANDS, MACD from the package. I tried this: "!pip install TA-Lib"
 and the "from TA-Lib import RSI, BBANDS, MACD". I receive a syntax error.

Comment: Can you try with pre-build package : `%pip install talib-binary` ?

Comment: Tried that as well, without succes.

Comment: Can you `print(dir(talib))` ?

Comment: Please see the colab file; https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1mFMTOygVcJxeJNnXHakuoid46uMfQ5xl?usp=sharing

Comment: I edit my answer, check it out ;)